# what is difference between the way to access sqlite and mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, qt, sqlite

In my experience: the way to access mysql's database ,  i should access mysql-server firstly and then access database..But if want to access sqlite's database, i can access database file directly , just by a file(.db), so easy..

**My question: can i access mysql database like sqlite ? Thank you!**

**The way to access mysql as follow:**

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
db.setHostName("localhost");
db.setDatabaseName("demo"); 
db.setUserName("root"); 
db.setPassword("root1");

if(db.open()) {
    qDebug("Make it");
} else {
    qDebug("Sorry");
}
```

**the way to access sqlite as follow:**

```
db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName("chat.db");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your particular position you cannot access it in the same manner. As Adrian mentioned, SQL Lite is an embedded database, meaning it authenticates differently from a server-client model of MySQL.

Because the MySQL database is not local to the device, you must then use a MySQL user to connect to it. Otherwise, you pose a large security risk, as anyone with the server information could connect using the same string you’d want to connect with.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean you want ot use MySQL as an [Embedded Database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database).

If so, you should read here: http://www.mysql.com/oem/